# Custom VM images for Google Cloud Dataflow workers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Having skimmed the Google Cloud Dataflow documentation, my impression is that worker VMs run a specific predefined Python 2.7 environment without any option to change that. Is it possible to provide a custom VM image for the workers (built with libraries, external commands that the particular application needs). Is it possible to run Python 3 on Gcloud Dataflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2021 Update**

As of today, the answer to both of this questions is YES.

1. Python 3 is supported on Dataflow.
2. Custom container images are supported on Dataflow, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44467369/1255356), and [this docs page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers?hl=en#docker).

---

> Is it possible to provide a custom VM image for the workers (built with libraries, external commands that the particular application needs). Is it possible to run Python 3 on Gcloud Dataflow?

No and no to both questions. You're able to configure Compute Engine instance machine type and disk size for a Dataflow job, but you're not able to configure things like installed applications. Currently, Apache Beam does not support Python 3.x.

References:

1. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params
2. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251
3. https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/

Comment: Just an update, I know it a very old answer but current version on apache beam for python supports python3

Comment: apologies for bumping an old thread, I understand that google dataflow currently supports custom containers, but does it support custom vm images for workers instances compute engine, I read through the documents and I couldn't find any. thanks for responding

Comment: the custom container images are only for the docker instances running inside the worker vm instances

Answer (score 4):

Python 3 support in to Apache Beam status:
https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/python-sdk/#python-3-support

Answer (score 3):

You cannot provide a custom VM image for the workers, but you can provide a setup.py file to run custom commands and install libraries.

You can find more info about the setup.py file here:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

[Custom containers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers) are now supported on Dataflow.