# Deploy DataFlow job using Scio

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I've started developing my first DataFlow job using Scio, the Scala SDK. The dataflow job will run in streaming mode.

Can anyone advise the best way to deploy this? I have read in the Scio docs they use `sbt-pack` and then deploy this within a Docker container. I have also read about using DataFlow templates (but not in great detail).

What's best?

Comment: You should define what _"best"_ means for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like for Java and Python version, you can run directly your code on Dataflow by using the dataflow runner and by launching it from your computer (or a VM/function).

If you want to package it for a reutilisation, you can create a template.

You can't [run custom container on Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465818/using-custom-docker-containers-in-dataflow).

Comment: How do you launch it and stop the client from being locked? For a streaming job I want Jenkins to launch the job, wait for it to start and then the pipeline go green.